# SQL Sum Rows that Share Values between Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join

I have two tables:

```
Country
|-----------------|
|Code | Population|
|-----------------|
|  1  |    10     |
|-----------------|
|  2  |    20     |
|-----------------|
|  3  |    30     |
|-----------------|
```

and

```
Borders
|---------------------|
| country1 | country2 |
|---------------------|
|    1     |    3     |
|---------------------|
|    1     |    2     |
|---------------------|
|    2     |    1     |
|---------------------|
```

Explanation of tables: Country with code 1 has population of 10, country with code 2 has population of 20, country with code 3 has population of 30.

Country with code 1 borders country 3, country with code 1 also borders country 2. Country with code 2 borders country 1.

How do I find the TOTAL population of each country's bordering countries? For example, the total population of country 1's bordering countries would be 30 + 20, or 50, because it borders country 3 and country 2.

I've tried using joins and sums, but I still do not know how to find this value for each country. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c1.Code, SUM(c2.Population)
FROM Country AS c1
INNER JOIN Borders AS b ON c1.Code = b.country1 
INNER JOIN Country AS c2 OB b.country2 = c2.Code
GROUP BY c1.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables

```
SELECT b.country1, SUM(c.population) AS Population
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN borders b ON c.code = b.country2
GROUP BY b.country1
```

And the output would be

```
-------------------------------------------
| Code       | Population                 |
-------------------------------------------
| 1          | 50                         |
-------------------------------------------
| 2          | 10                         |
-------------------------------------------
```